# Displaying 3D Pdf in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-chrome, pdf

I've need to display a 3D Pdf file on my web page. So now I'm trying to do it like a simple pdf.

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="Pdf/MyFile.pdf" width="500" height="500"></object>
```

Also I've try this:

```
<iframe src="Pdf/MyFile.pdf" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The proble is with Chrome browser. Chrome doesn't display the content of the file(Opera works fine). Also if I use simple pdf without 3d model it display in Chrome correctly.

What can I do to displat 3D pdf in Chrome to?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following syntax for view pdf on browser:

```
 <object type="application/pdf" data="MyFile.pdf" width="500" height="500"></object>
```

Comment: I have use it, as you can see.

Comment: please check data attribute in that i have remove pdf

Comment: this is path. "Pdf/" is folder name.

Comment: But it's working both way, I have try that solution also

Comment: Ok. But as you can see that's works for Opera and for simple pdf. So, there is no problems with path.

Comment: which type of pdf you want to show can you give one example

Comment: I'm speaking about Pdf with embeded 3D model. Like this one: http://www.pdf3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Voxler3-Iridium-Geobody.pdf